# Writing to text, logging errors C#

Tags: c#

I have one output and 8 inputs. All inputs shall have the same value as the output. This procedur will be looping many times until i stop it. What I need help with is to create one more log file to log if any error occurs with the out/in. It must contain every error (which input or output) with date and time. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
string tot = Convert.ToString(totalFaults_1);
    if ((out != "1") || (in_1 != "1") || (in_2 != "1") 
                     || (in_3 != "1") || (in_4 != "1") 
                     || (in_5 != "1") || (in_6 != "1")
                     || (in_7 != "1") || (in_8 != "1"))
                {
                    totalFaults_1++;  // Total number of errors.
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\TotalFaults_1.txt", tot);
                   /* here I need to know which input (1-8) or the output is failing
                      and put date and time for each error*/
                 }
```

Comment: Have you considered a logging library like [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)?

Comment: Probably `System.IO.File.AppendAllText` instead of `WriteAllText`

Comment: @Igor I've never used Log4Net. I'm quite new to C# coding...

Comment: @DmitryBychenko the first text file is correct, all i need is a total number. What i want is to create a new text file with all other info described in my question...